# stackView in the center scrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uistackview

I want `stackView` will be in the center `scrollView`. Items of `stackView` can be equals 2 items or 15 items. 
But the elements always should be in the center.

For example, if we have only one element it locates in center screen. If we have 10 items and `stackView` larger than a mobile screen we can scroll `ScrollView` and see all elements.

my [project](http://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2uKHFTccFnWQkpibGRLNnJQVFE)

Look upon my screenshots, I hope it helps to understand that I try doing.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why don't you use just `UICollectionView`

Comment: @Jack I thought 'stackView' it a good idea) Okay, how can I add the cell of the 'collectionView' in center screen?

Comment: "Centre of screen" can you explain more?

Comment: @Jack I want to add images dynamically. For example, I add only one image in my cell. How can I see it in middle on screen? Look on the second screen.

Comment: Allright, you should try with `UICollectionView`, make  `leading` `trailing` constraint constant ~150, ~150. then on run time if items are greater than 3, update the constraint constant with 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are going with the UICollectionView as @Jack said then you can use below approach
Calculate the number of cell and screen width based on that set left values for UIEdgeInsets

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    let leftPadding: CGFloat = collectionView.bounds.width/2 - 20 // image width/2 = 20 in your case
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: leftPadding, bottom: 0, right: 0)
}
```

Comment: You offer me, calculate width stackView and after add left padding for stackView if it needs? It's interesting I will try it realization.

Comment: Currently, I am working on the same thing using collection View using the approach I posted, once I figured out my calculations will update the answer. for you is straight forward you already have the width of the image fixed you want to centre

Comment: I use this code         scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: stackLeading, bottom: 0, right: 0) instead of your code. But I have problem when I swipe scrollView in left, it returns automatically.

Comment: what do you mean by returns automatically?

Comment: Look on this video, please: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xaHETm_-Grjsph7x1ZstDM2gJ15Glgy6

Comment: Update your question with latest code, what you are doing while scrolling or scrolling did end?

Answer (score 0):

This code work for me fine.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //MARK - Properties
    let countImages: CGFloat = 21
    let widthImage: CGFloat = 40
    let spacingImage: CGFloat = 10.0
    let scrollViewHeigh: CGFloat = 48.0
    let stackViewHeigh: CGFloat = 28.0

    //MARK - ViewController Life cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        prepareUIView()

    }

    //MARK - Methods
    func prepareUIView() {

        //Stack View
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.horizontal
        stackView.distribution  = UIStackViewDistribution.equalSpacing
        stackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.center
        stackView.spacing = spacingImage

        //set images to stack view
        let imageViews = getImageView()
        imageViews.forEach {
            stackView.addArrangedSubview($0)
        }

        //scroll View
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false

        scrollView.addSubview(stackView)
        view.addSubview(scrollView)

        scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

        //Constraints
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        scrollView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: scrollViewHeigh).isActive = true

        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: stackViewHeigh).isActive = true

        let allImagesWidth = countImages * widthImage
        let allSpacingWidth = (countImages - 1) * spacingImage

        let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        let stackWidth = allImagesWidth + allSpacingWidth

        let halfScreenWidth = screenWidth * 0.5
        let halfStackWidth = stackWidth * 0.5

        let leadingStackViewConstant = halfScreenWidth - halfStackWidth

        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: leadingStackViewConstant, bottom: 0, right: 0)

    }

    private func getImageView() -> [UIImageView] {

        var imageViews = [UIImageView]()

        for _ in 0..<Int(countImages) {
            let imageView = UIImageView()
            imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "mastercardIcon")
            imageViews.append(imageView)
        }

        return imageViews

    }

}
```

Comment: leadingStackViewConstant check this value, and read about contentInset, suppose you have set 100 to left, even though you can see content, you can't actually scroll. read this doc.. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/CreatingBasicScrollViews/CreatingBasicScrollViews.html

Comment: @IraniyaNaynesh explain, please. How using your code?